# Kerberos authentication issue on jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Recorded the script using jmeter. While replay the script I am getting the below errors. I have modified krb5.conf and jaas.conf files as well . in the http authorization manager I have given baseurl and username ,password,domain,realm,machanism

while ping our website, i got the below servername(chvpkw8.chvpk.test.net). so i assumed chvpkw8 was the server name and chvpk.test.net as a domain name.

So  in the authentication manager, i have given full name chvpk.test.net as a domain and chvp4kw804.chvpk.test.net as a realm name. pls correct me my krb5.conf and jaas.conf. and let me know i want to be modified any other information as well.

NEGOTIATE authentication error: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: No valid credentials provided

Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: java.io.IOException: Configuration Error:
    Line 11: expected [option key]
    at sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.(Unknown Source)

```
     Krb5.conf

  [libdefaults]
      default_realm = chvpk.test.net
      default_tkt_enctypes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96,aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96
      default_tgs_enctypes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96,aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96
     forwardable=true

       [realms]
        chvpk.test.net = {
    kdc=134.248.10.25
    admin_server=134.248.10.25
          }

         [domain_realm]
         134.248.10.25=chvpk.test.net
        .134.248.10.25=chvpk.test.net

       and jaas.conf file 

         JMeter {
com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
doNotPrompt=false
useKeyTab=false
storeKey=false
debug=true
      };
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of your `jaas.conf` file is not very correct, you are missing a semicolon after `debug=true` line

```
JMeter {
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
    doNotPrompt=false
    useKeyTab=false
    storeKey=false
    debug=true;
};
```

Other configuration seems to be good (as long as it matches configuration on the KDC side)

References:

- [JAAS Login Configuration File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/tutorials/LoginConfigFile.html)
- [Windows Authentication with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-apache-jmeter)